# Generic method returning objects of generic derrived types

Tags: c#, generics

I am struggling with generics in C# a little bit. Consider this piece of code:

```
public interface A {};
public interface B : A {};
public interface C : A {};

public interface IMyInterface<in T> where T : A {};

public class FirstImpl<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : B {};
public class SecondImpl<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : C {};
```

now I need to some factory, which takes a type and returns the correct implementation:

```
public IMyInterface<T> Create<T>() where T : A 
{
    if(typeof(T) is B) {
        return new FirstImpl<T>();
    }
    if(typeof(T) is C) {
        return new SecondImpl<T>();
    }
}
```

this doesn't work on two levels. the first one is return type. The second one is that I can't pass "T" into first or second implementation, since they require more specific type. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Well, the problem is technically you can't convince the compiler here that the generic type T is actually a B or B derivative when you're invoking `new FirstImpl<T>();`. Interesting. Food for thought. Lemme see.

Comment: Did you leave out a couple of `new` keywords? It's hard enough to understand the question, without having to deal with code that wouldn't compile even if it did what you wanted. Did you intend to write `return new FirstImpl<T>();` and `return new SecondImpl<T>();`?

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have code using a generic type or method, and that code does some sort of test on the generic type parameter, you're doing it wrong. (And IMHO it goes without saying that dropping into reflection is even worse.) The whole point of a generic type is to write code that *doesn't* depend on the generic type.

In your example, a better approach would be something like this:

```
static IMyInterface<T> CreateB<T>() where T : B
{
    return new FirstImpl<T>();
}

static IMyInterface<T> CreateC<T>() where T : C
{
    return new SecondImpl<T>();
}
```

I.e. write different methods to handle each scenario. The caller is going to have to know what it's dealing with already anyway, if a constraint-based approach was going to work. So it's not a problem to just have different method names, each to be used in the appropriate and respective situation.

If the above does not address your specific scenario, please improve the question so that it includes a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows not only the generic types you are trying to use, but also the context in which they will be used.

Comment: What you says does make perfect sense. I'll consider that. There is no need for wider improvements of code sample, all of you got it right. (All types are pretty much simple... I am just making experimental framework and we want super flexibility for experiments which is why am I trying to parametrize everything. )

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind reflection, you could do it that way:

```
public static IMyInterface<T> Create<T>() where T : A 
{
    if (typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        var type = typeof(FirstImpl<>);
        var boundType = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
        return (IMyInterface<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(boundType);
    }
    else if(typeof(C).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        var type = typeof(SecondImpl<>);
        var boundType = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
        return (IMyInterface<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(boundType);
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("unknown type " + typeof(T).Name);
}
```

You can try it in a [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cgLloH)

Comment: reflection is fine. let me try this.

Comment: var type = typeof(FirstImpl<>) and what goes into "<>" ?

Comment: typeof(FirstImpl<>) represents the unbound type. You can check the .net fiddle which I added.

Comment: I made a incy wincy refactor to the fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UGFrze)

Comment: nice. your refactoring makes your use case more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would be to just add the extra constraints with the  `Create<T>()` method like `public IMyInterface<T> Create<T>() where T : A , B, C` if you want to keep the design intact. You'd probably need one implementation for the default case to make the method complete.

```
public IMyInterface<T> Create<T>() where T : A, B, C
{
    if (typeof(T) is B)
    {
        return new FirstImpl<T>();
    }
    if (typeof(T) is C)
    {
        return new SecondImpl<T>();
    }
    return new DefaultImpl<T>;
}
```

Comment: I will try this approach, stay tuned. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Cool! I only answered on the premise that you want to keep the design same here, if you're open to change it, you might get better design friendly solutions than this. :)

Comment: Actually on the second thought I am not sure if this is possible, since T might be only B or only C, not both.

Comment: I am open to any better solution than mine. :)

Comment: And for a redesign I'd give it a shot. Would take a while as this is a very barebone sample. :)

Comment: I am getting "No implicit reference conversion from D to C" where 
D is implementation of B only.

Comment: Are you pointing to something like [this](https://gist.github.com/thehoneymad/7a7f20fa0b28e21fa8b5323ef9248b26)?

Comment: I have left you comment there which might be little more specific about my usecase.